# ArrayList won't store more than one string value passed from another intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, arraylist

My problem is that I have an intent which is sending string value to my MainActivity. I am trying to save those values in ArrayList but only the last one is displayed.

Here is my MainActivity:

**EDIT:**

```
package com.example.olev.shoppinglist;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import java.util.ArrayList;



public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

ArrayList<String>productNames=new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;


public void addNewProduct(View view){
    Intent i = new Intent(this,AddProduct.class);
    startActivity(i);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    addToList();
    ListView productList=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.productList);
    adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,productNames);

   productList.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public void addToList(){
    Bundle itemData=getIntent().getExtras();

    if(itemData==null){
        Log.d("EmptyExtras", "EmptyExtras");
        return ;
    }
    String product=itemData.getString("product");
    adapter.add(product);

}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

My AddProduct:

```
package com.example.olev.shoppinglist;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;




public class AddProduct extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_product);
}

public void sendProductToMain(View view){
    EditText productName= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.productName);
    String product= productName.getText().toString();
    Intent i = new Intent (this,MainActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("product",product);
    startActivity(i);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_add_item, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

**I am having an error like this after I added adapter.add("product"):**

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.olev.shoppinglist/com.example.olev.shoppinglist.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ArrayAdapter.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ArrayAdapter.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
            at com.example.olev.shoppinglist.MainActivity.addToList(MainActivity.java:45)
            at com.example.olev.shoppinglist.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

How is it possible to have Nullpointer after this if clause and how i should fix it in order to get dynamical item adding to ListView.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is restoring `productNames` *twice*, first in `onCreate()`, and again in `onRestoreInstanceState()`. After the first restoration, you append the new product String to the restored list. But then you restore it a second time, which replaces the updated list with the original list.

Try deleting your `onRestoreInstanceState()`.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an ArrayList from savedInstanceState instead of getIntent().getExtras() and you said you wanted to send it with an intent. savedInstanceState is for when the activity is recreated, and intent is when you open a new activity. If you want your data to be sent from an activity to another, then you should have :

```
productNames = getIntent().getExtras().getStringArray("products");
```

savedInstanceState will help you keeping a string array for exemple on screen rotation since the activity is recreated in this situation, but when the activity is first created savedInstanceState is null, so it doesn't even go in your 'if'.

Comment: I am trying to get one edittext value as string from AddProduct and save it to arraylist in MainActivity. For some reason if i try to add first time it is successful, but if I want to add second item, the first one gets overwritten ,not stored as second value in Arraylist.